# Asp.net and Jquery Tree

Tags: asp.net, jquery, treeview

I need a tree that I can add nodes to, and save to the database once all the desired nodes have been added.

I have looked into TreeView server side control, but I wanted to check out the Jquery tree as well. I realize that I will have to use JSON web services to write the data to the database (or retrieve it). I am new to Jquery. Can someone point me to a simple example that uses Asp.net and Jquery?

I am using asp.net 3.5/c#/VS 2008.

what I would like to know as well:
1) does JSON return strings from web services or objects (while inside Jquery)? I am very used to being able to return objects from Web Services, and if I have to de-serialize the strings, it could get too messy as I have fairly complex structures.
2) what is the learning curve for this type of set-up and where do i start? My experience mainly lies in server programming; and I have OK knowledge of Javascript.

I am going to consider pros and cons and choose between TreeView (server side web control) or JQuery tree + JSON.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) jQuery is very easy to learn - 1h and you're more then up and running.

2)

> does JSON return strings from web services or objects (while inside Jquery)

Yes.

http://west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/42319.aspx

http://west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/896411.aspx